# how to write an image into doc file in asp.net C# without other dll's

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am looking to write an image into doc file ..

here is the code that i am trying...

```
string imageFolder = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["coverLetterPath"].ToString();
string imageName = "images.jpg";
string path1 = Path.Combine(imageFolder, imageName);
// Create a file to write to.
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path1))
{
    sw.WriteLineAsync(imageName);
}
string fileName = string.Empty;
fileName = "BodyContent_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyy_HHmmss_fff") + ".docx";
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(path1);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

here the file that i am creating is downloaded but the image is not loaded into that file.. getting a message when i open the doc as **File is corrupted**

Comment: it's just a guess here but try converting it to a byte[] and add that to the file, see if that works..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write an image from byte\[\] into MS WORD using C# Windows application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567042/how-to-write-an-image-from-byte-into-ms-word-using-c-sharp-windows-application)

Comment: Saving a .jpg file with a .docx extension does not make it a word document